# Is it possible to create Language Identifiers (for syntax highlight) based on specific directories instead of file extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Vistual Studio Code, I can create [`file-associations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) relating file extensions to a specific language syntax.

However, I have a particular case where files inside a subdirectory may or may not have extensions... In fact, files can have all sorts of extensions, but they all use a sepcific language syntax.

Is it possible to create a more flexible file-association rule that scans certains subdirectories of my project to apply a language syntax?

Working around this, I created a broad file-association that matches any file, similar to this:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*": "nginx"
},
```

Except, this rule applies to the entire project. I would like to restrict this to a particular subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Django extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) I found an example of more complex file association

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},
```

You can find a bit more info about [glob patterns](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview).

You can have these patterns defined on a folder/workspace level if needed.